# Few commits are missing after using -f push in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have deleted the larger file accidentally pushed into one of our gerrit project using below commands.

```
1. Clone the project
2. git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/heavy.file' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
3) git push origin --force --all
```

Now some of the commits are missing/gone from our remote project `master` branch. So now how do i revert the commit that i pushed forcefully (Or) how do i restore the missing commits?

`git log` doesn't shows the commit that i pushed. Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The the commands you mention are not visible in the question. In general though a force commit changes history. Best bet is to work with team mates who may have the original history in their local clones.

Comment: The way is to inform members to push the changes again?

Comment: I have those missing commits in my gerrit web, but in git repository not there.

Comment: How much time elapsed between steps 1 and 3? Is the reason commits are missing because new commits appeared on `master` between your steps 1 and 3?

Comment: Almost 4 hours. totally 22 commits are missing.

Comment: If anyone still has the missing commits anywhere, just do a forced push from there. And in the future, avoid forced pushing unless you're really sure it's what you want to do.

Comment: Also, using `--all` with `--force` is *really* asking for trouble! Best to force push just one branch at a time, when you're sure your local copy of that branch is the one you want to force push.

Comment: Since I had the missing changes on gerrit. So performed `cherry-pick` and pushed it. Now i could see the missing changes in my git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, we know that the reason this happened is because 22 new commits appeared on `master` during the 4 hours of time between when you cloned, and when you force pushed back out the rewritten repo.

To get those 22 commits back:

1. Lock the `master` branch so no one else commits to it while you're fixing it. (In retrospect you could have prevented the problem by locking during your previous re-write too.)
2. Make note of the previous tip of `master` before your rewrote the repo. Let's call that commit `M1`.
3. Find the new tip commit ID of the previous `master` with those missing 22 commits. It sounds like you already found it from gerrit. Anyone who had previously fetched would have had it as well, and also the person (or thing) that created that last commit would have known it. Let's call that commit `M2`.
4. On your rewritten repo, checkout master: `git checkout master`
5. Now cherry pick the range of 22 commits: `git cherry-pick M1..M2`
6. Now push out your re-written commits: `git push`

Note you shouldn't have to force push `master` in the last step. If you do have to force push, that means your Lock in the first step didn't work and someone added new commits again. You could reset your local `master` to the new tip, and repeat these steps, or fetch and then `git rebase origin/master` which *should* rewrite your 22 commits on top of the newest `master` again. Finally, you can `git push` again without force and you'll know you're fully up to date.

**Tip:** Anytime you plan to force push a shared branch, best practice is to notify your team and then lock the branch so no one can commit to it.